# how to use @foreach inside AJAX & jQuery code for insert Multiple rows Data in Laravel 8

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-8, laravel-blade

The code it works normal when i put option in static mode, for example:

[image]

```
"<select name='id_post[]' id='' class='form-control'>"+
   "<option value='1'>A</option>"+
   "<option value='2'>B</option>"+
   "<option value='3'>C</option>"+
"</select>"+
```

but it doesn't work when I use the foreach loop in the script so adding doesn't work

```
<script>
    $('thead').on('click', '.addRow', function(){      
        var tr ="<tr>" +
                "<td style='display:none;'><input type='text' name='id_article[]' value='{{ $article->id_article }}' class='form-control'></td>"+
                "<td>"+
                "<select name='id_post[]' id='' class='form-control'>"+
                    "@foreach ($posts as $post)"+
                        "<option value='{{ $post->id_post }}'>{{ $post->description }}</option>"+
                    "@endforeach"+
                "</select>"+
                "</td>"+
                "<td><input type='text' name='price[]' class='form-control'></td>"+
                "<td><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='btn btn-danger deleteRow'>-</a></td>"+
                "</tr>";

    $('tbody').append(tr);

    });

    $('tbody').on('click', '.deleteRow', function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `@foreach` out of the concatenation:

```
<script>
    $('thead').on('click', '.addRow', function(){      
        var tr ="<tr>" +
                "<td style='display:none;'><input type='text' name='id_article[]' value='{{ $article->id_article }}' class='form-control'></td>"+
                "<td>"+
                "<select name='id_post[]' id='' class='form-control'>";
                @foreach ($posts as $post)
                tr += "<option value='{{ $post->id_post }}'>{{ $post->description }}</option>"
                @endforeach
                tr += "</select>"+
                "</td>"+
                "<td><input type='text' name='price[]' class='form-control'></td>"+
                "<td><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='btn btn-danger deleteRow'>-</a></td>"+
                "</tr>";

    $('tbody').append(tr);

    });

    $('tbody').on('click', '.deleteRow', function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
</script>
```

This *should* work, haven't tested it

Comment: I move the @foreach out of the concatenation but i have the same problem

Comment: This is inside a `.blade` file, right? Did you check the source to make sure everything's ok? Maybe `console.log(tr)` before `$('tbody').append(tr);`